# Bar Graph, graphing Integers as strings

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-analysis

"Gender" is stored as an integer: 1 and 0
I am trying to graph it in a bar chart as "Male" and "female" on the X-axis
compared with total number of bets by gambler.

I think there is an easier way of doing this rather than changing every input in the dataset into a string.

I am than trying to give male a blue color and female purple or yellow.

thank you everyone

code:

```
# scatter plot of age of Gamblers correlated with number of bets 
#alpha keeps from over plotting remove if unnecessary
p_1 <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = Gender, y = BetsA )) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.1)
p_1 + ggtitle(label = "Gender Correlated with Total Number of Bets") + # for the main title
xlab(label = "Gender of Gambler") + # for the x axis label
ylab(label = "Total Number of Bets" ) # for the y axis label
```

[image: current viz]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to first convert your `Gender` column to a `factor`. Afterwards you could use the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete` to assign your desired labels for 0 and 1. And for coloring you could basically do the same. Just map `factor(Gender)` on the `color` aes then set your desired colors via the `values` argument of `scale_color_manual`:

Using some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

# Create example data
data <- data.frame(
  Gender = rep(c(0,1), 100),
  BetsA = runif(200, 0, 40000)
)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data, aes(x = factor(Gender), y = BetsA, color = factor(Gender) )) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.1) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c("0" = "Male", "1" = "Female")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("0" = "blue", "1" = "purple"), labels = c("0" = "Male", "1" = "Female")) +
  ggtitle(label = "Gender Correlated with Total Number of Bets") +
  xlab(label = "Gender of Gambler") +
  ylab(label = "Total Number of Bets" )
```

[image]

Comment: hmm is there a way to make the dots bigger, add more numbers on the Y axis and make the columns of male and feel thinker, or a better graph? perhaps I should do a pie chart instead? what do you think is better for data analytics, this seems flawed and messy.

Comment: (: You could increase the size of the dots via `size`, e.g. `geom_point(alpha = 0.1, size = XXXX)`. To get more numbers (I guess axis text labels?) you could use the `breaks` argument of `scale_y_continuous`, e.g. `scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 40000, by = 5000))`. Concerning the best viz I would suggest to start with a boxplot. Or show both a boxplot and the single data points side by side. See e.g. this blog post: https://www.cedricscherer.com/2021/06/06/visualizing-distributions-with-raincloud-plots-and-how-to-create-them-with-ggplot2/